# kuka_grasp_block_playback.py from bulletphysics/bullet3 (pybullet library) not running on my system.

Tags: robotics, reinforcement-learning, bulletphysics, openai-gym, kuka-krl

I downloaded the bullet3 github repository (Bullet Physics SDK) from **https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3.git** which contains python bindings for OpenAI Gym examples to run Reinforcement Learning Algorithms. 
I tried running the kuka_grasp_block_playback.py example present in the following directory: `bullet3-master/examples/pybullet/examples/`
My system does not support pybullet.GUI and so I went ahead with pybullet.DIRECT.
But, on running it using `python kuka_grasp_block_playback.py`, its giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kuka_grasp_block_playback.py", line 92, in <module>
stepIndex = int(p.readUserDebugParameter(stepIndexId))
pybullet.error: Failed to read parameter.
```

How to deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an out-of-date question, but just in case:. the latest version of pybullet contains a similar KUKA grasping implementation as OpenAI Gym environment. Just run 'sudo pip install pybullet' to get it.

This gym environment can be run without GUI without issue. See the quickstart guide at http://pybullet.org for more info about those pybullet Gym environments for Deep Reinforcement Learning.

The readUserDebugParameter only executes when using GUI mode, it fails in DIRECT mode, so just comment it out.